# How to Install LuaFileSystem?

Tags: lua

I'm making a lua application and I am going to need the LFS. However it gives me an error while installing.

```
`Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>luarocks install luafilesystem
Installing http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luafilesystem-1.6.2-2.src.
...

7-Zip 9.10 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-12-22

Processing archive: luafilesystem-1.6.2.tar.gz

Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2.tar

Everything is Ok

Size:       122880
Compressed: 27886

7-Zip 9.10 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-12-22

Processing archive: luafilesystem-1.6.2.tar

Extracting  pax_global_header
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\Makefile
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\Makefile.win
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\README
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\config
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\config.win
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\examples.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\index.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\license.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\luafilesystem.png
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\doc\us\manual.html
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.3.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.0-2.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.1-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.1rc1-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.4.2-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.5.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.6.0-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.6.1-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-1.6.2-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-cvs-1.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\rockspecs\luafilesystem-cvs-2.rockspec
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\.gitignore 
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\lfs.c
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\lfs.def
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\src\lfs.h
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\tests
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\tests\test.lua
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6\lfs.def
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6\luafilesystem.dsw
Extracting  luafilesystem-1.6.2\vc6\luafilesystem_dll.dsp

Everything is Ok 

Folders: 7 
Files: 31
Size:       86449
Compressed: 122880
cl /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/lfs.obj -IC:/Program Files/Lua/5.1/include src/lfs.c
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error: Build error: Failed compiling object src/lfs.obj

C:\Users\user>`
```

I was running as Admin. I have tried looking at other posts and looking at the manual, but to no avail, Can someone help?

Comment: Obviously, you must only use it in a working build environment.

Comment: @Deduplicator Forgive me for not knowing, but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: THe explicit error you get is, that `cl` is not recognized. Unless you have the Microsoft compiler installed and run this in your buil environment it also creates, the error won't go away.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Microsoft C compiler. There are other C compilers for Windows but they might not have compatible switches.

Microsoft hasn't shipped a C compiler independent of Visual Studio since they began the free Express edition. [Install it](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop) and you should be good to go.

Build environment means that various environment variables, esp. PATH, are set up for the compiler. This is set up by running a [batch file the VS provides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx). There could be a shortcut for it but if not (I suspect the Express version might not) look for a file like vc*.cmd or vc*.bat and create a shortcut to it or just run it at your command prompt.